# Xcode 3.2 documentation, missing symbol definitions like CGPoint?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode

I went into Xcode -> Preferences -> Documentation and grabbed everything there that makes sense. Yet when I option+click common symbols like CGRect or CGPoint I get:

Documentation not found for the symbol 'CGPoint'. Click here to view symbol declaration.

This wasn't an issue with versions previous to Xcode 3.2.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're option-clicking I believe only symbols in the frameworks you are linking to in your current Xcode project are looked-up. Is your current project linked against AppKit and/or CoreGraphics?

-W

Comment: Hi Wil, this is actually for an iPhone app.. so I'm linking against UIKit, but not AppKit. What's funny is, now whenever I start a brand new project, all the frameworks are shown in 'Red', as if they don't exist. Apps still compile though.. really odd 3.2 behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest AppKiDo for documentation reference.  It really allows one to find documentation easily and allows easily finding methods to solve problems.  It uses the Apple supplied documentation, just parsing it and presenting it in a very usable fashion.

AppKiDo is a reference tool for Cocoa programmers. The latest release, with source code, can be downloaded from http://homepage.mac.com/aglee/downloads. AppKiDo is free.

Answer (score 0):

I see those just fine- are you sure in the documentation window in the Doc Sets dropdown, that you have the iPhone OS library checked?  You can have any number of doc sets loaded, but will generally only have a few selected...

Comment: There is no option to 'check' it, but I most certainly did hit 'Get' on it.

Comment: There should be something that adds a checkmark next to the doc set, in the top of the window you use to actually read the documentation - I'm not talking about XCode preferences where the "get" buttons are.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Xcode, the documentation is not loaded initially.  You have to manually launch the documentation and subscribe to the documentation you want.  You only need to do this once, but you will need to do it once after every Xcode installation.  If you've just upgraded from leopard/xc3.1 to snowleopard/xc3.2 that would make sense it's not working yet.